# Is there a symbol for asymptote?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation, asymptotics

Is there a symbol for asymptote?  At the moment I’m labelling them with limit notation, i.e.,

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = -5$$

to describe an asymptote running parallel to the $x$-axis at $y=-5$.

I’m hoping there exists just a compact symbol that means asymptote when all other information in the limit notation is present elsewhere in the graph, such as on the axis.

Comment: You may want to look at the $f\sim g$ notation described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I would simply use a sentence "The function $f(x)$ has a [horizontal/vertical/oblique] asymptote at ...".

Comment: Thanks @dua this was what I was looking for.